# Why is the graph of the implicit relation $\sin(x^2+y^2) = \cos(xy)$ so cool?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, soft-question, graphing-functions

I found a **VERY** interesting graph. It looked very, very cool, but the equation of the graph is so simple! Here is the image of the graph:

[image: Cool graph]

My question is: can someone explain to me how each of the different parts of the equation affects the graph? How does the $\sin(x^2+y^2)$ affect this graph? How does it help to create such a cool looking pattern?

Comment: A nice one is also this one http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28|x|^0.5%2B|y|^0.5%29+%3D+cos+%28x+y%29%2C+%28x%2C-40%2C40%29%2C%28y%2C-40%2C40%29

Comment: @Nameless If I stare at it long enough, the graph seems to move in all directions away from the centre. Should be one of those optical illusions

Comment: Notice $$\begin{align}
\sin(A) = \cos(B)
\iff & B = \pm ( \frac{\pi}{2} - A ) + 2m\pi \quad\text{ for some }\; m \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\iff & A \pm B = (2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\quad\text{ for some }\; n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$$
Substitute $x^2+y^2$ for $A$ and $xy$ for $B$, you get a bunch of ellipses of the form
$$x^2+y^2 \pm xy = (2n + \frac12)\pi.$$
The key is using the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to create multiple contour lines from a single pair of function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some observations to try to explain what is going on.

First of all, **why does there appear to be concentric repetition of the image expanding outwards?** This is caused by the periodicity of sine and cosine. Each pair of crossing ovals happens periodically, but not at a constant period. Since the input is quadratic in the variables, the period is shrinking as we move outward, making the repetition more frequent. I tackle this later on by looking at radial slices and equations of the ovals.

Secondly, **why are there pairs of intersecting oval shapes?** As one quickly guesses, the graph has 90 degree rotational symmetry. The transformation $(x,y)\to(y,-x)$ carries solutions of the equation to other solutions. Obviously $x^2+y^2=y^2+(-x)^2$, and $\cos(xy)=\cos(y(-x))$ since cosine is an even function.

One can try to get a grip on the solutions closest to the origin and the subsequent repetition by considering radial slices of the plane. The first two to investigate would be the one with $x=0$ (Which covers the y=0 case, after symmetry.) you would be solving the equation $\sin(y^2)=1$, which happens whenever $y^2$ hits $\pi/2 + n2\pi$.

The solutions on the line $x=y$, for example, would have to satisfy $\sin(2x^2)=\cos(x^2)$. Actually, you an work out what the equation should be for $y=kx$ for any constant k.

---

*Added for completeness:*

**Are they actually ellipeses? Yes!**
Achille Hui provided a derivation of why the ovals are really ellipses in comments to the original post. I'm echoing part of it here to make it a little more visible and durable.

Using these equations:

$$\begin{align} \sin(A) = \cos(B) \iff & B = \pm ( \frac{\pi}{2} - A ) + 2m\pi \quad\text{ for some }\; m \in \mathbb{Z}\\ \iff & A \pm B = (2n+\frac{1}{2})\pi\quad\text{ for some }\; n \in \mathbb{Z} \end{align}$$

substitution gives the form of the ellipses:

$$x^2+y^2 \pm xy = (2n + \frac12)\pi$$

*Work of my own expanding on this:*

If we had a family of equations of concentric circles $x^2+y^2=an+b$ for constants $a,b$ and natural number $n$, then we would recognize that the square of the radius varies with $n$, so the radius should vary as $\sqrt{n}$, and we would expect the radii to be "slowing down" since the values of $\sqrt{n}$ get closer together as $n$ increases.

Rotating this family of equations by $\pi/4$, we can eliminate the $xy$ term and think about the ellipses as basic ones we do in calculus. Here's the rotated version using $+$ for the $\pm$ part of the equation above:

$$
\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}=2\pi n +\frac{\pi}{2}\\
3x^2+y^2=4\pi n +\pi\\
\frac{x^2}{(\frac{4\pi n+\pi}{3})}+\frac{y^2}{4\pi n+\pi}=1
$$

So here we can see that the major and minor principal axes vary similarly to $\sqrt{n}$, and moreover that the major principal axis is $\sqrt{3}$ times that of the minor axis. If you do the same trick with the "$-$" for $\pm$, you get the other family of ellipses rotated $\pi/2$ from these ellipses.